# How to get Firestore documents and display them on a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xcode11

[Screenshot of Firestore Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGGCK.jpg)
I want to display the "first_name" field for each document in the collection (In the UITableView. The UITableView just shows up blank every time I run the app.

CODE:

import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var filterButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var userTableView: UITableView!

var usersArray = [String]()
var db: Firestore!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userTableView.delegate = self
    userTableView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    loadData()

}


func loadData() {
    db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                self.usersArray.append(document.documentID)
            }
        }
        print(self.usersArray)

        self.userTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("Tableview setup \(usersArray.count)")
    return usersArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = userTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.fullNameLabel.text = user
    print("Array is populated \(usersArray)")

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you registered the cell to the tableView. Try using: `tableview.register(UserCell,forCellReuseIdentifier:"Your reuseIdentifier string")`. Try inserting this in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I can also suggest two things: When `print`(self.usersArray)` (before `self.userTableView.reloadData()`) or `print("Tableview setup \(usersArray.count)")` print, do they output the proper values? If you say yes to both, then your implementation of the UITableView must be reviewed. The other suggestion is to replace `return cell` with `return cell!`. Hope that helps.

Comment: okay, they are not printing anything so it's definitely a problem with that. any ideas on what I could try to fix this issue of them not printing out the proper values?

Comment: Oh okay, that's a step in a good direction. The next step is to trace the source of the problem. If `self.usersArray` is not populating with data, ask yourself, why? It looks like `document.documentID` is a string that is suppose to populate `self.usersArray`. What you can do is print the value of `document.documentID` before `self.usersArray.append(document.documentID)`, if a string prints, you're good. If not, you should check how you're pulling data from Firebase and correct it.

Comment: I've managed to print the data and it's accurate. Only problem is that it's still not showing up on the UITableView.

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help btw.